# How Plausible is Restoration of Cryonically Preserved People?

Tags: cryonics

I fear death (so much that I'll prefer a year/few of torture over death), and plan to sign up for cryonics. I would like to know how plausible it is, why the answer would be so, and if possible how many years away would revival be.

Thanks.

I have read a lot of articles on Alcor, and done several hours of research since yesterday. Mainstream Science seems to assign infinitesimal probabilities against, it, but the guys at Alcor (and other Cryonic institutes like Cryonics.org think they've got a case). It seems theoretically possible to me, but I don't want to but into too much hype—so how plausible is it?

Comment: Not even the "world's leading cryonics company" wants to give any kind of estimate. http://www.alcor.org/FAQs/faq01.html#patients

Comment: I've browsed their FAQs; I want information from a non biased source.

Comment: I think @skymningen's point is that if even the biased source isn't promising anything, the plausibility is vanishingly small.

Comment: You browsed their FAQ, was there any data? Have they accomplished a successful freeze/thaw? Do they have stability data? Safety data?

Comment: Vitrification of a Rabbit brain and devitrification was done, and the brain was successfully preserved in perfect condition (they didn't bother reviving it though.

Answer (score 1):

Largely implausible, mainly due to damage from freezing. This type of damage even happens when food is frozen (although flash-freezing decreases it).

More feasible approaches for avoiding death would include machine-replacement parts, lab-grown transplants, neural backups, and regenerative gene modifications. I'm surprised no one has considered studying hibernation and how to add similar genes to humans that would enable hibernation.

Comment: They don't freeze people—they vitrify. Freezing damage doesn't happen. Downvoting for not bothering to acquaint yourself with the process before condemning it.